# How to add a description to an Excel AddIn

Tags: vba, excel

How do I add a description to an Excel AddIn like in the picture below:

[image: Excel AddIn Manager]

You can see the Euro Tools AddIn has one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like so:

File, Info, Properties, Advanced properties. Click the Summary tab. The Title is what shows up as the name of your add-in. The Comments section shows up as description.

Comment: To get the xlam file open in a way that let me get to the File > Info menu, I had to use the VBA window to select the "ThisWorkbook" object under "Microsoft Excel Objects" and edit the IsAddin property to False. Then I changed this property back to True after editing the Title and Comments as described here.

Comment: That is why I develop my addins in xlsm files. When a version is ready for publication I save-as to xlam. This is also a more secure method as xlam files will not trigger a save changes prompt, even if you made modifications.